# jquery - adding fields to a form dynamically - post is missing data when you submit form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

**Background Information**

I have a form that among other things, allows the user to dynamically add first name / last name text fields using jquery.

**Problem**

When The user submits the data, the additional fields & data that was created via jquery is missing from the POST.

**Test Details**

Using the "addname" button, I add two or three additional names besides the default fname / lname fields that are on the form.  And then I submit the data.  The data is missing the dynamically added fields.

**What I've Tried / Checked**

1. Ensured that as I add new rows of "first name" / "last name" text boxes, each control has a unique "name".  As you can see, I assign a custom class name to the first name field, and then in jquery i take count of how many first name fields I already have.  I increment that value by 1 and then bake the new number into the names of the new text fields I created.  using the F12 debug window, I can see the HTML code has these counters baked into the names.
2. Ensured that the rows of dynamically added data are within the `<FORM>`
3. Ensured that I have a submit button within the FORM.

I'm not sure what else I should check.

If you have any suggestions, I'd appreciate it.

```js
//Here's of the two jquery methods I have that allows users to dynamically add new fields / data to the form: 

$("#addname").click(function() {
  var numItems = $('.widgetname').length; //count all items with widgetname class
  numItems += 1;
  htmlstring = "<tr>";
  htmlstring += "<td><input class='form-control widgetname' type='input' placeholder='First Name' name='fname" + numItems + "'/></td>";
  htmlstring += "<td colspan='2'><input class='form-control' type='input' placeholder='Last Name' name='lname" + numItems + "' /></td>";
  htmlstring += "</tr>";
  $("#tcsection").before(htmlstring);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="btn-warning">
      <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    </td>
    <tr>
      <?php echo form_open( 'widget/assign'); ?>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" name="widgetlist" id="widgetnum">
            </select>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" placeholder="Site:" name="site" id="site">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <input class="form-control" type="input" placeholder="Location" name="location" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <input class="form-control" type="input" placeholder="Department" name="department" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="listofnames">
        <td>
          <input class="form-control widgetname" type="input" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="form-control" type="input" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <button id='addname' type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tcsection">
        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
</table>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">
      <h2>TC</h2>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tcs">
    <td>
      <input class="form-control starttc" type="input" placeholder="UTC Start Time (format 00:00:00)" name="starttime" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" type="input" placeholder="UTC End Time (format 00:00:00)" name="endtime" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" type="input" placeholder="Extension" name="extension" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" type="input" placeholder="Domain" name="domain" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id='addtc' type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="submitbtnsection">
    <td colspan="5">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Assign Widget" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

Comment: True @mplungjan - I didn't read very far before I commented and now see his problem isn't what I thought it was.

Comment: Can you post HTML code we can actually test? Yours has PHP in it.

Comment: Try moving the form open outside the table. I see weird html: `<tr>
      <?php echo form_open( 'widget/assign'); ?>
      <tr>` PS: You should never use `name="submit"` for any form element if you plan to submit the form using script. It will overwrite any submit event handler

Comment: @mplungjan the form is not submitted via script

Comment: But is the HTML generated by your PHP valid?

Comment: @mplungjan your first comment was the answer... i moved the open form statement to outside the table and that worked!  if you want to post as an answer, I will accept...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the form open outside the table.

I now see weird html:

```
<tr> <?php echo form_open( 'widget/assign'); ?> <tr>
```

intead I expected

```
<?php echo form_open( 'widget/assign'); ?>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="btn-warning">
      <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    </td>
```

PS: You should never use name="submit" for any form element if you plan to submit the form using script. It will overwrite any submit event handler